# How to rename a repo that is on git branch: gh-pages through the command-line?

Tags: git, github, command-line, github-pages

I have read on the Git docs for removing and renaming remotes that the solution is " $ git remote rename pb paul $ git remote origin paul " (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) but I believe it works for the repo that are only on the master. Any ideas? I been trying with the solution above and the repo is not being renamed.

Comment: note that renaming a remote doesn't change anything about the repo to which it's pointing.  You aren't changing that repo's real name for instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename a remote with:

```
$ git remote rename <current name> <new name>
```

You can remove it with:

```
$ git remote rm <remote to remove>
```

It doesn't matter what branches a remote contains or is tracking.

Answer (score 0):

#### Rename local branch:

```
git branch -m <new_name>
```

#### Delete the old remote branch

```
git push --delete origin <old_name>
```

#### Push the new remote branch

```
git push origin <new_name>
```